# css border-width percentage

Tags: html, css, border

I have one div wrapping another like so

```
<div id="container"><div id="box"></div></div>
```

Let's say the container has a dimension 100px by 100px.  I want to box to have 0px height and 0px width.  However, I want the left border of the box to fill up 50% of the container, and the right border of the box to fill up the the other 50% of the container.

How do I do this with css?

Comment: Why not just have two `DIVs` with 50% width each?

Comment: because I want the trapezoid shapes of the borders

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do what you are after, but using linear-gradients instead of borders.

Use the following markup:

```
<div class="box"></div>​
```

And the following styles (example: http://jsfiddle.net/HxbnK/):

```
.box {
    background-image: linear-gradient(154deg, red 50%, transparent 50%),
                      linear-gradient(26deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}​
```

Just keep in mind that the `.box` element needs to be a square for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `px` to `vw` like

```
border-width: 10px;
```

to

```
border-width: 10vw;
```

Its do whats percentage do....

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it is not supported by many browsers though.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

Short of manually calculating and specifying `50px` as the border width, you can't. The `border-width` property only accepts lengths or the keywords `thin`, `medium` and `thick`.

As Saad Imran suggests, you might be able to just use two `div`s with 50% width each.

Comment: but i want the trapezoid shapes of the border....basically if i make border-width: 0% 50% 80% 50%; I will be able to have a triangle within the box.  Then I can draw a another div below the box to make a tree trunk!!!  with the triangle on top being the tree leaves!

Comment: I want to have a lot of random sized trees with various heights in teh trunk and leaves.  Anyway, I cheated for now by doing this http://jl.evermight.com/sunrise/ .  Would be good if i could change those tree leaves to be triangles.