# responsive CSS3 triangle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a responsive triangle piece to one of my divs (does not have to be IE8 compatible). I am struggling with making it responsive

http://jsfiddle.net/KzqB3/2/

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    width: 90%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 2%;
    border-left: 275px solid transparent;
    border-right: 275px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #4679BD;
}
.content { width: 90%; background-color: #4679Bd; }
.content p { color: #fff; padding: 15px 0; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph inside this div</p>
</div>
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: should it be the width of the blueu div?and should it be verticaly responsive to?

Comment: You may need to approach this differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380759/css-border-width-percentage

Comment: No..I think there is a way

Comment: @Ani I am almost 100% sure there is not a way. Your best bet, especially if you don't need IE8 support, is to use an `svg` image which can scale to any size or html5 canvas.

Comment: @JoshPowell Found it. Check answer

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KzqB3/20/)

**CSS**

```
.triangle{
   width: 56%;
   height: 0;
   padding-left: 45%;
   padding-top: 45%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle div {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0;
   margin-left:-500px;
   margin-top:-500px;
   border-left: 500px solid transparent;
   border-right: 500px solid transparent;
   border-top: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
 .content { width: 90%; background-color: #4679Bd; }
.content p { color: #fff; padding: 15px 0; margin: 0; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
   <p>Paragraph inside this div</p>
</div>
<div class="triangle"><div></div></div>
```

Comment: I would not call that responsive but it's a nice work a round. On wider screens the triangle will break away from it's parent and shot downward. The OP, I'm guess, does not want the height of the triangle to grow. Last an `svg` image would be far superior then this option in practical situations.

Comment: I had that before using this as my starting point http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/ however the triangle cant be an equilateral, has to be similar to my fiddle where it is isoceles, cant have a massive point

Comment: what ani posted works responsively its just not the triangle im looking for

Comment: I'll try to make it isoceles