# How do i turn my triangle responsive?

Tags: css

I'm trying to put my triangle responsive, because it only works on desktop computers, how can i do that?

I have a code here, and i want to turn my div into a responsive div, for mobile phones, tablets...

triangle code:

```
*{
background-color: black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}


.triangle-down {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 642px 187.5px 0 187.5px;
border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

html code

```
<div class="triangle-down"></div>
```

Comment: If you want the border to scale properly, measurements would need to be in percent. Unfortunately border-width doesn't work with percent. You could either use media queries and break points, or linear gradient. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380759/css-border-width-percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not mind using background-radient, this could be an alternative as body background:.
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mBjtC

```
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      to top left,
      black,
      black 50%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0)) top  center no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(
      to top right, 
      black, 
      black 50%, 
      #007bff 50%, 
      #007bff     )  top center no-repeat;
    background-size:40% 200%;/* set your own values and units here */
    background-color: black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
}
html {
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use percentages instead of pixels, you can work out the equivalent by dividing the pixel size by the context, which is usually the size of the body container which you haven't declared but is usually 1000px for ease. To use ems, it's divided by the base piel size, or you can use a converter, if you haven't declared a base font size it's usually 16px http://pxtoem.com/